# QXmlStreamAttributes how to modify an attribute?

Tags: evaluate, qt5.5

I have attributes stored in an instance of QXmlStreamAttributes, the attribute values may contain expressions which are evaluated at run-time.

When I evaluate an expression I want to update the value in the collection.

Is it possible to modify an attribute value and update the original entry?

A lot of the methods available in the QXmlStreamAttributes class use indexes to reference an attribute, there is a replace method, but how to you get the index of a specific item in the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

First using the reference to the collection, get the 'indexOf' the attribute using its attribute name and current value.

The once the index is known use the 'replace' method to replace the attribute at the specified index with the new attribute.